# Why does only one of my three-way switches work suddenly?

Tags: electrical, switch, walls

I have two toggle wall switches at opposite room ends that control a ceiling light fixture. Only one switch (main) now works for off and on of fixture, the other will only turn fixture off not on.

Until recently both switches worked for on/off options.

Comment: Light is on. Flip switch # 2 and the light goes off. Flip it back and the light *stays* off? Or is it: Light is on. Flip switch # 1 and the light goes off and then flip switch # 2 and the light *stays* off?

Comment: That sounds like a misconfiguration, which means you're mistaken about it ever working. Either that or something's loose.

Comment: did you use the back stab method

Comment: It sounds like you will be checking/replacing a switch.  They are three way switches so make sure you take pictures and label wires before removing wires from the switch.  Three ways are confusing if you only guess what wire goes where after.